# assertThrows fails in Spring Batch with Tasklet

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm throwing an IllegalStateException in a `Tasklet`'s `execute()` method based on a condition and I am trying to test my Batch-Job like so:

```java
@Test
void testJobThrowsMyException() throws Exception {
        JobParameters emptyJobParameters = new JobParameters();

        assertThrows(IllegalStateException.class, () -> jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob(emptyJobParameters));
}
```

Here's the execute method:

```java
@Override
public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) {
        getWorkload(chunkContext).forEach(workloadItem -> {
            // Processing 
        });

        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
```

And this is basically how it gets the workload:

```java
private int getWorkload() {
        if (condition) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Thats the exception i want to test");
        }
        
        return workload;
    }
```

The problem is, based on the logs of the test execution, the exception is thrown, but the test fails with the following message:

`org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Expected java.lang.IllegalStateException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.`

But as already said the logs clearly state that the exception was thrown:

```
10:32:54.608 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: 
10:32:54.616 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep - Applying contribution: [StepContribution: read=0, written=0, filtered=0, readSkips=0, writeSkips=0, processSkips=0, exitStatus=EXECUTING]
10:32:54.616 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep - Rollback for RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Es ist noch keine Liefernummer in den ImportDetails vorhanden.
10:32:54.618 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate - Initiating transaction rollback on application exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Thats the exception i want to test
at [...]
10:32:54.619 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Initiating transaction rollback
10:32:54.619 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Rolling back JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(1793816221<open>)]
10:32:54.619 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl - rolling back
10:32:54.620 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Closing JPA EntityManager [SessionImpl(1793816221<open>)] after transaction
10:32:54.621 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate - Handling exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException, caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Es ist noch keine Liefernummer in den ImportDetails vorhanden.
10:32:54.621 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate - Handling fatal exception explicitly (rethrowing first of 1): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Es ist noch keine Liefernummer in den ImportDetails vorhanden.
10:32:54.622 [main] ERROR org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep - Encountered an error executing step my-step in job my-job
```

And im not catching this exception, so why does the test fail, could anyone please explain?

Best regards

Comment: Because Spring Batch is handling the exception, it doesn't propagate outside of Spring Batch. Which is also what the log you are adding is telling you (see the last 3 lines). Based on that exception Spring Batch will mark your job as failed with a message/cause).

Comment: I second what @M.Deinum said, and I was writing an answer along those lines with an example.

Answer (score 0):

When an exception is thrown in one of the steps of your job, it is not thrown to the client of your job. It is rather saved in the `failureExceptions` of the `JobExecution`.

In your case, you need to get a handle to the job execution returned by `jobLauncherTestUtils` and assert that the execption is part of `JobExecution#failureExceptions`. Here is a quick example:

```
@Test
void testJobThrowsMyException() throws Exception {
   // given
   JobParameters emptyJobParameters = new JobParameters();

   // when
   JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob(emptyJobParameters);

   // then
   assert that jobExecution.failureExceptions contains an IllegalStateException
}
```